# Migration WSO API Manager 1.4.0 to 1.8.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to migrate from WSO2 API Manager 1.4.0 to 1.8.0. I executed all instructions from 'wso2am_1.8.0/dbscripts' (how it was possible)

- migration 1.4.0 to 1.5.0
- migration 1.5.0 to 1.6.0
- migration 1.6.0 to 1.7.0
- migration 1.7.0 to 1.8.0

But the very last ant script 'swagger-doc-migration' (from 1.7.0 to 1.8.0)  failed and showed exception like this:

```
2015-01-20 16:32:47,142] ERROR - RPCMessageReceiver Resource does not exist at path /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/SOME_API-1.0-xxxxxxxx-AT-xxxxxxxxx.com/1.2
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)...
```

It seems scripts 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 doesn't migrate swagger docs completely because 'swagger-doc-migration' script (1.7.0->1.8.0) can't find path `/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/SOME_API-1.0-xxxxxxxx-AT-xxxxxxxxx.com/1.2`. 
So, how can I make "swagger-doc-migration" from "migration 1.7.0 to 1.8.0" work?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in swagger resource migration script and it was fixed in the latest patch.

Please use the scripts from following location : https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.8.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/

Comment: Thank you for advice. Unfortunately I have the same effect. May be I don't need to execute the last step of migration (1.7.0->1.8.0)? Will the API Manager 1.8.0 work without it?

Comment: You have to migrate from 1.7.0 to 1.8.0. There are major changes, including DB changes. Have you tried what I posted as answer?

Comment: Yes, I've done steps from 1.4.0 to 1.6.0 and the last steps I've taken from branch you mentioned. I had the same issue. Migration from 1.7.0 to 1.8.0 script "swagger-doc-migration" failed with exception mentioned in this post.

Comment: It seems, I'm not alone. Abimaran, what do you think about this?

Answer (score 0):

have the same issue with migration. I try to migrate 1.6.0 -> 1.7.0 -> 1.8.0 and swagger-doc-migration fails for the step 1.7.0 -> 1.8.0. But if I setup 1.7.0 and then migrate to 1.8.0 swagger-doc-migration succeed.
Seems like swagger-doc-migration from 1.6.0 -> 1.7.0 fails to migrate api docs correctly.
Note: I've tried https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.8.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/ from Abimaran Kugathasan's answer.